# <Provider /> outside or <Router /> outside>?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

Usually(react-router + redux):

```
<Provider store={store}>
 <Router>
    <App />
 </Router>
</Provider>
```

Why not the other way around?

```
<Router>
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
</Router>
```

Follow up question: to setup authentication, when `LOGIN_SUCCESS` action is fired, we need to save the returned token into `window.localStorage` and **redirect the page**. So I write success handler inside redux middleware:

```
const localStorageMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  if (action.type === 'LOGIN_SUCCESS') {
    if (!action.payload.error) {
      window.localStorage.setItem('jwt', action.payload.token)
    }
  } else if (action.type === 'LOGOUT_SUCCESS') {
    window.localStorage.setItem('jwt', '')
  }
  next(action)
}
```

Then I feel the need to access `history.push` to do redirect(that's why I ask the first question, trying to get access to `location` inside `redux` code), how do I do so?

Comment: what version of `react-router` are you using?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<Provider store={store}>
 <Router>
    <App />
 </Router>
</Provider>
```

redirecting:

```
// top-most line of the reducer
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

const localStorageMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  if (action.type === 'LOGIN_SUCCESS') {
    if (!action.payload.error) {
      window.localStorage.setItem('jwt', action.payload.token);
      browserHistory.push('/');
    }
  } else if (action.type === 'LOGOUT_SUCCESS') {
    window.localStorage.setItem('jwt', '')
  }
  next(action)
}
```

I'd take the logic to the `actions` file, not the `reducers`.

Comment: Cool. By the way, where wrap provider around Router, not the other way?

Comment: I use promise middleware to handle actions, so I can't do .then() stuff in actions, right?